# Difference between sizeof(str -1) and sizeof(str) -1?

Tags: c++, c, sizeof

I came across sizeof(str -1) a couple of time on net but never used it myself. I am just curious what is the difference between sizeof(str-1) and sizeof(str) -1 where str is the character array say char str[] = "Hello";

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sizeof(str)` is the size of the array `str`. In this case, that's 6 (including the nul terminator). So `sizeof(str)-1` is 5 (it excludes the nul terminator).

`str-1` has type `char*` in C and `const char*` in C++, because of array-to-pointer decay. So `sizeof(str-1)` is the size of a pointer-to-char. It has nothing to do with the length of the particular string used to define `str`.

As an aside, computing `str-1` is undefined behavior. Conveniently `sizeof` doesn't evaluate its operand, so that's not an issue here.

Answer (score 5):

(According to debugging when compiled for 64 bit) it's a big difference.

```
int main( void ) 
{
    char str[] = "Hello";

    sizeof( str-1 ); //gives 8
    strSize = sizeof( str ) - 1; //gives 5
}
```

The first instance is giving the size of a pointer because the argument is the result of pointer arithmetic, the second gives the size of the string, less one.

( The size of your pointers may vary.  :-) )